# jQuery refresh div only when change happen in server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using jQuery to refresh the content in "container" which works fine to refresh contents every 9 seconds and fetch the data from feed.php and show in "container".

What is the best pactice to refresh the "container" only if there is a change in feed.php otherwise show the same content?

Simple html:

```
<body>
<ul id="container"></ul>
</body>

<script>
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#content').hide();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#content').show();


            },
            success: function() {
                $('#content').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#content");
        $container.load("feed.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('feed.php');
        }, 9000);
    });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this return diff status values from php like

```
$response[errCode] = 0;
$response[errCode] = 1;
```

and in ajax call put a condition like:

```
success: function(response) {
if(response == 0)
    {
       // refresh the container
    }
}
```